# Android 32-bit service on aarch64

Tags: android, service, 32bit-64bit, abi

I'm trying to deploy a *system service* on Android running on 64-bit ARM (aarch64).

The service cannot be built for aarch64 (due to portability issues), and only runs when build for 32-bit ARM.  I am able to install and run it when built for 32-bits, but I'm concerned if it might cause any other problems.

PackageManager outputs warnings about incompatible ABIs, and also I found a reference that says "All apps that use a given sharedUid are expected to use the same instruction set". In my case, sharedUid is android.uid.system

**Can someone help clarify what are the implications of installing a 32-bit program in a 64-bit Android system, especially as a system service?**

Thanks,
Erez